# How to Format this type of URL in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, url

Hey Friends,

I am using the following API for getting details of IMDB,http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/?q=Star+Trek
while i using following API i am getting URL as following Output

http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0796366\/

how can i change it to

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0796366/

in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [stripslashes](http://php.net/stripslashes):

```
$url = 'http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0796366\/';
$url = stripslashes($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0796366\/";
$url = str_replace("\/","/",$url);
```

example here http://ideone.com/J44Q6

Comment: strange that this got downvoted since it works (see above) - not saying its the best solution but its a different one

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = str_replace('\', '', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL has been escaped - that is, it has had a back-slash character added in front of certain other characters which could cause issues, eg if they were put into a SQL string.

PHP has a command [`stripslashes()`](https://www.php.net/stripslashes) to remove these escape characters.

However, the feature of PHP adding the slashes automatically is old and is now deprecated. If possible, you should check your PHP.ini and turn off the `magic_quotes` option. That way you won't get the slashes added to your input any more, so you won't have to remove them.

Note that if you are writing data to a database, you will need to escape it before putting it in your SQL string. But you should use something like `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead of the slashes added by magic_quotes.